# Touch screen communication

Tags: serial-port, touchscreen

I have with me 3 Beckhoff control touchscreen panels.  Some multi-touch some single-touch,

There is no manual anywhere, I'm only capable of running them as windows monitors, but i want to make programs that capture the coordinates of my touch and do something with them,
(that done on different platforms like arduino, python, ...)

How do I use the USB or Serial interfaces to communicate with the touchscreen? How do I know its output when I press somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on arduino, you have the possibility of [serial communication](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/serial) with the example [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample). The second thing is, that arduino native programming language is C and the last thing is, that the controller of the touchscreen has some pins. Some are tx pins some are power pins. To find out which is which is your task. Google around to find out the pinouts. Maybe have a look at the chip on the controller and find a datasheet to it and then trace the vias to the pins and read them with the serial communication pin rx on your arduino.

Comment: Of course assuming, that your controller is serial. If you had the arduino due, it has even an usb port for peripherals such as touchscreen.